# date period FROM S3 using NiFi

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-nifi

please tell me how to get data from S3 using nifi for a period (for example from 2021-12-01 to 2021-12-31), what I need to write in routeonattribute? thanks

Comment: Not enough information to answer.

Comment: What data? Data within 1 file, or files within a range? Where is the range coming from? Filename, metadata? You need to provide more details on what your setup looks like and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Attribute Values
filename
export/dt=2021-09-01/user=284/cro.parquet I made the following thread: lists3->routeonattribute->fetchs3object->updateattribute->updaterecord->convertrecord->putdatabase

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.